# How to manage state in a large Flutter application using the Cube library?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I’m working on a large-scale Flutter application and I’m having trouble managing the state. The application has multiple screens and complex user interactions. I’ve noticed that some widgets are not updating correctly when the state changes.

What I’ve tried: I’ve tried using setState to manage the state locally within each widget, but this is leading to a lot of code duplication and it’s becoming difficult to keep track of the state across different parts of the app. I’ve also looked into using InheritedWidget, but I’m not sure if this is the best approach for a large application.

Expected Outcome: I recently came across the Cube library, which is the most recent state management library in Flutter. It uses dependency injection without requiring code creation. I’m looking for a more scalable way to manage state in my Flutter application using the Cube library. Ideally, I would like a solution that allows me to easily track state changes across different parts of the app and minimizes code duplication.

Comment: and why `Cube`, why not obuse de facto standards like `Bloc`, `Provider`, `Riverpod`?